# compare multiple values with multple values in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, match

I have a data frame with 2 columns, "time and "a".

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), a = c(3, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5))
```

How is it possible to compare if the values changed over time? I need a new column "comp" in the data frame that shows if the third value in column "c" is the still the same as the last two values and the two values before in the same column. So the result could look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), a = c(3, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5), comp = c(F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F)
```

In the end I need to compare a column with about 3 mio. observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(comp = a == lag(a) & a == lag(a, 2) & a == lead(a) & a == lead(a, 2))

#   time a  comp
# 1    1 3 FALSE
# 2    2 8 FALSE
# 3    3 2 FALSE
# 4    4 2 FALSE
# 5    5 2  TRUE
# 6    6 2 FALSE
# 7    7 2 FALSE
# 8    8 4 FALSE
# 9    9 5 FALSE
```

Comment: nice and easy solution :) what if I would like to compare specific values. For example the result is only True if there are twos (like in my df example) who haven't changed or (as a condition) sixes?

Comment: You can just keep adding conditions to the right-hand side of the `comp = ...` statement, such as `& a == 2`.

Answer (score 3):

A similar solution to @Bas using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, comp := a == shift(a) & a == shift(a, 2) & 
                  a == shift(a, type = 'lead') & a == shift(a, 2, type = 'lead')]

#   time a  comp
#1:    1 3 FALSE
#2:    2 8 FALSE
#3:    3 2 FALSE
#4:    4 2 FALSE
#5:    5 2  TRUE
#6:    6 2 FALSE
#7:    7 2 FALSE
#8:    8 4 FALSE
#9:    9 5 FALSE
```

Comment: thanks for your data.table solution! What if I want to check for example the next 20 values? There must be a better solution than write `shift(a, 1)`, `shift(a, 2)` etc.... because if I try `setDT(df)[, comp := a == shift(a, type = "lag", n = c(1:2)) & a == shift(a, type = "lead", n = c(1:2))]` I get an error: `'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: You can use a rolling operations. Check out `zoo`s `?rolapply` function. You may ask a new question if you have trouble implementing it for your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you're looking for values that are the same as their 2 adjacent values on either side, and in this case you're happy to ignore the 'missing' adjacent values for the 2 first & 2 last values.

Using base R:

```
sameasadj=function(v,n=2,include_ends=T) {
    if(include_ends){vv=c(rep(head(v,1),n),v,rep(tail(v,1),n))} 
    else {vv=c(rep(NA,n),v,rep(NA,n))}
    sapply(seq_along(v),function(i) diff(range(vv[i:(i+2*n)]))==0)
}

df$comp = sameasadj(df$a)
df$comp
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Explanation:

`sameasadj=function(v,n=2,include_ends=T)` = define function sameasadj to test whether each value is the same as its adjacent neighbours on each side.  We can give the option to choose the number n of adjacent neighbours (in your case 2), and whether-or-not to include the ends (or to return 'NA' for these, since they lack enough neighbours on one side).

`if(include_ends){vv=c(rep(head(v,1),n),v,rep(tail(v,1),n))}` = if we want to include the ends, then we just add the 'missing' neighbours so that they match

`else {vv=c(rep(NA,n),v,rep(NA,n))}` = otherwise we add 'NA' values

`sapply(seq_along(v),function(i)` = go along each position i in the vector...

`diff(range(vv[i:(i+2*n)]))==0)` = ...and check whether the elements from i to i+2*n are all the same (`diff(range(x))==0` will return `TRUE` if all elements of x are the same)

Putting it all into a function makes it easy to change your mind later about the number of adjacent neighbours, or what to do with the ends...